# HtmlAgilityPack SelectNodes only where an attribute is missing or not defined

Tags: attributes, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

I have an HTML document which has different tables in it.

Simple examples include 2 types:

1. `<table>`
2. `<table class="footer" id="some-x">`

To select all nodes where the table has an attribute called `id` I can use

`DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id]")`

What I'm tying to figure out of the opposite, how do I select nodes where the tables do *NOT* have any attribute called `id` (or any class, i.e just bare tags) (example 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not()` to select tables that don't have any `id` attribute :

```
DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[not(@id)]")
```

...or to select tables without any attribute at all :

```
DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[not(@*)]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work here. Let me know if it doesn't

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Where(t => !t.HasAttributes)
```